# How can i know if this is the first time in the action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC project. one of my Models are called 'ASR'. in 'ASRController' i have  a few actions, Including: `public ActionResult Index()` which is a Get.

The `Index()`Action happens on the first display of the page (Get). I want to make it possible that inside this Action i can diffrenciate and write different pieces of code for the first time this Action is being called upon in my entire running of the project and other times (In other words,  if its the first time that the View of this page is shown - Should do so and so... and if we already had that view shown and then we went somewhere else in the project ('website') and came back to this page it should do somthing else...)
I tried searching to find an answer, but no luck...
Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve your goal is like this:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Session["AsrIndex"] == null)
            {
                Session["AsrIndex"] = DateTime.Now;
                return View("Index");
            }
            return View("Index1");
        }
```

The above action will work like this:

1. First time when you run this action the `Session` will be null, and the action will return view "`Index`"
2. Second time `Session` will not be null, and the action will return view `"Index1"`

3rd, 4th, ... run of this action will return `Index1`

Comment: session will be reset with the app pool recycles.  after the app pool recycle it will look like a first visit again.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your controller actions check for the existence of a cookie.

```
        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["<action name>"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("<action name>"));

            //do your first time stuff
        }
        else
        {
            //do not first time stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Various ways to do this :-

1. Create a global static variable in your controller and increment it in Index Action .
2. Create Session